# How to make a list of numbers out of strings in a list of lists in Python

Tags: python, string, list, integer

I have a list like this:

```
[[['(0,1,2)','(3,4,5)'],['(5,6,7)','(9,4,2)']],[['(0,1,2)','(3,4,5)'],['(5,6,7)','(9,4,2)']]]
```

And I would like to get something like:

```
[[[[0,1,2],[3,4,5]],[[5,6,7],[9,4,2]]],[[[0,1,2],[3,4,5]],[[5,6,7],[9,4,2]]]
```

I've tried string comprehension, the re module, splitting, stripping but none seem to work. Thanks!

Comment: To convert '(0,1,2)' to [0,1,2] you can use below                                         [int(i) for i in re.split(r"\\(|\\)|,", '(0,1,2)')[1:-1] ]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recursion seems quite straightforward:

```
l = [[['(0,1,2)','(3,4,5)'],['(5,6,7)','(9,4,2)']],[['(0,1,2)','(3,4,5)'],['(5,6,7)','(9,4,2)']]]

def convert(x):
    if isinstance(x, list):
        return [convert(y) for y in x]
    else:
        return [int(y) for y in x.strip('()').split(',')]

convert(l) # [[[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5]], [[5, 6, 7], [9, 4, 2]]], [[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5]], [[5, 6, 7], [9, 4, 2]]]]
```

Comment: By the way, how would you deconvert the list?

Comment: @ThomYorke If you mean converting the list back to original format I'd write same kind of recursive function that would stop recursion when it encounters a sublist whose elements are integers (and not lists). Then I'd convert that sublist to a string and return it to caller.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to see what it looks like in nested list comprehensions

```
startList = [[['(0,1,2)','(3,4,5)'],['(5,6,7)','(9,4,2)']],[['(0,1,2)','(3,4,5)'],['(5,6,7)','(9,4,2)']]]
new = [[[[int(x) for x in moreSub.strip("()").split(",")] for moreSub in subitem] for subitem in item] for item in startList]
print(new)
```